# js, and css not appearing after installing gitlab

Tags: apache-http-server, git, css, gitlab

I have `gitlab` installed on port 8088 on top of an existing `apache` on `CentOS 6.5` and I used this tutorial `https://about.gitlab.com/downloads/#centos6`

Because I also use apache on this server, I altered the apache vhost file to have the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName git.server.net
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  AllowEncodedSlashes Off

  <Location />
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8088
    ProxyPassReverse http://git.server.net/
  </Location>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule .* http://127.0.0.1:8088%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA]
</VirtualHost>
```

and altered `/etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb` to this:

```
external_url 'http://git.server.net:8088'
```

`# service httpd restart` works fine but when I do a `# gitlab-ctl reconfigure` it throws up a lot of warnings (but it all works) except that every single gitlab stylesheet or js include is missing so it looks like this:

[css failure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbTlV.png)

in the html source if I visit the css or js file it throws up the following error

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator,
 root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS) Server at git.server.net Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

obvious nginx is supposed to `parse` these file extensions and apache is not meant to : is there anyway to make this internal relative urls reference

**EDIT**
This relative url reformat *does* work but if I go there as a url manualy it works: how do I get gitlab to append the :8088 to a relative url? - 
http://git.server.net:8088/assets/application-2684b1e4bc7f333c28c683e130ee05f0.css

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing the vhost config to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName git.server.net
  DocumentRoot /opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/public

  ProxyRequests off
  ProxyPass / http://git.server.net:8088/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://git.server.net:8088/
</VirtualHost>
```

I will leave this up for anyone who has this issue in the future